# Show the option of the drop down list that is equal on the variable on the url

Tags: php

I have the following drop down list. How can I show the correct option based on the url e.g. www.domain.com/?car=Algema&city=Paris

What I did is add a `value="echo $_REQUEST['car'];"` because I used the same on my textboxes but it is not working.

I am using PHP.

```
<select name="car" value="echo $_REQUEST['car'];" id="car" class="select">
<option value="Algema">Algema</option>
<option value="Barkas">Barkas</option>
<option value="Cadillac">Cadillac</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You need `<option value="Algema" selected>Algema</option>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="car" id="car" class="select">
<option value="Algema" <?php echo $_REQUEST['car'] == 'Algema' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>Algema</option>
<option value="Barkas" <?php echo $_REQUEST['car'] == 'Barkas' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>Barkas</option>
<option value="Cadillac" <?php echo $_REQUEST['car'] == 'Cadillac' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>Cadillac</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have 104 different forms and some of them are containg more than one dropdownlist. It is impossible to replace them. Is there a way to replace the `$_GET['car']` with the `$_GET['get the name of select id or name automatically']` ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer with PHP specific code but you need to set the `selected` attribute of the `option` you would like to select to `selected`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="car" id="car" class="select">
  <option value="Algema" <?=($_GET['car'] == 'Algema') ? 'selected="selected"' : NULL?>>Algema</option>
  <option value="Barkas" <?=($_GET['car'] == 'Barkas') ? 'selected="selected"' : NULL?>>Barkas</option>
  <option value="Cadillac" <?=($_GET['car'] == 'Cadillac') ? 'selected="selected"' : NULL?>>Cadillac</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have 104 different forms and some of them are containg more than one dropdownlist. It is impossible to replace them. Is there a way to replace the `$_GET['car']` with the `$_GET['get the name of select id or name automatically']` ?

Comment: No, you need to know the select drop down name in order to check which item has been selected.